# When a monk mitigates all the damage due to the Slow Fall feature, does he/she still fall prone?

Tags: dnd-5e, class-feature, monk, prone, falling

So let's say I deliberately fall let's say 20 feet, I will take 2d6 points of damage. As a monk at 4th level I get slow fall which will let me nullify fall damage 5× monk level. So at 4th level, I get 20 nullification. So even under the scenario when the die maxes out which would be 12, so I fall prone when I land?

The rules in this case say:

> A fall from a great height is one of the most common hazards facing an adventurer. At the end of a fall, a creature takes 1d6 bludgeoning damage for every 10 feet it fell, to a maximum of 20d6. The creature lands prone unless it avoids taking damage from the fall.
>
> — *Player's Handbook*, p. 183

So do I fall prone or no?

Comment: Is there a reason you think this happens or do not happen? It's not really clear to me what is confusing you about this.

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance.

Answer (score 33):

### No

You do not land prone when you reduce the damage to zero. You've basically answered your own question with this PHB quote (page 183, "Falling"):

> The creature lands prone, unless it avoids taking damage from the fall.

You did not take falling damage, so you do not land prone.

Comment: Well no harm in confirming XD